How to ACK PubSub push subscription events for long running tasks using Flask?
I am using EventArc to generate events and process them using Cloud Run. It uses Cloud PubSub as transport layer.
Following the solution explained here, my code has the following structure.
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    # Extract Pub/Sub message from request
    envelope = request.get_json()
    message = envelope['message']

    try:
        # Process message
        # ...
        time.sleep(200)

        # Acknowledge message with 200 OK
        return '', 200
    except Exception as e:
        # Log exception
        # ...

        # Message not acknowledged, will be retried
        return '', 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8080, debug=True)

The problem is that my messages are NOT acknowledged when the processing takes more that 1 min : the processing tasks works and return 200 Ok BUT the event is still not ACKed.
Thus Pubsub topic send the same messages over and over.
Why are my messages not ACKed ? and how to solve it ?
There are propositions to immediately acknowledge the message upon reception, how to do it and continue the processing ?
PS:
I initally had the problem that PubSub did not wait for processing thus I augmented my ACK deadline according to recommendations here and did set it to 10mins (my processing takes between 1 and 3mins).
I also changed my minimum time before retry according to recommendations here and did set it to 9min50s.

Hi @nprime496, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

There is no built-in solution with Eventarc right now. Your only solution is to ack the service!
Let me explain. When you create an Eventarc, a PubSub topic and a PubSub Push subscription is created. The idea here is to "manually" update the PubSub Push Subscription configuration to set the ack deadline to 10 minutes.

Manually is not the correct word. I automated it in one of my project with terraform + a post bash script (based on the terraform output and thanks to a gcloud command to update the subscription created by Eventarc). In fact it's always an home made hack.

Hi, thanks for your answer, I believe that I've already done it. My problem is that even after my function completes and sends 200 OK, the message is not acknowledged by pubsub. It keeps sending it. I do not understand why.

It's strange, your piece of code should work if the ack deadline is correctly set. Eventarc is nothing more than an umbrella that manage multiple service and component conveniently, but do not change their initial behavior (i.e. PubSub ack mechanism)

Changing my Cloud Run service account solved the issue. I used a different service account than the eventarc Trigger receiver service account. I guess that the Cloud Run SA must have the roles/eventarc.eventReceiver role.
For debugging, look at the Eventarc console to see if ACK responses are received.
